# 500 Internal server error with new php files on server (Wordpress/Woocommerce)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, .htaccess, internal-server-error

I am getting a strange 500 Internal Server Error with a new script I am trying to implement in the actual site. Here's a screen:

![500 Internal][1]

I can route to this files manually without problems and they are working too. But not in the script itself. The Paths are also correct.

Heres the link to the Site:
[>>> Link <<<][2] (just enter R10369 in the input field or a random number)

Everything else is working correctly except these 3 files:

```
reseller.php, 
checkresellerid.php, 
resellermail.php
```

I googled a bit and everywhere is the .htaccess mentioned. but I never modified it or overwrited it. What could be the Problem? Thanks for any Help and sorry for my bad Englisch.

(Let me know if you want to see the php files)

EDIT: I managed to include my new php files into wordpress but i still got the 500 Error

Comment: Can you please copy your .htaccess content? Edit it in your question and I may can help you.

Comment: I cant find any .htaccess file on my server(I checked "show hidden files and dotfiles) Where should it be located?

Comment: It's in your root folder. or folder where the wordpress is installed.

Comment: searched the whole server. no .htaccess was found :(

Comment: posted an answer for this problem, I realized that WP doesn't let you use .php file calls.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the website.

I  think Wordpress doesn't let you call .php inside of it's system.
I mean you cannot call PHP files for ajax.

You need to use wordpress ajax. Here is a snippet how to use ajax:

```
Function.php in your theme file.

function myajax()
{
 //do stuff
 die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_product_s', 'myajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_product_s', 'myajax' );
```

And in your javascript file using jQuery:
The url may change, maybe it's enough to have wp-admin/admin.ajax.php or something like this, i don't really remember right now.

```
    $.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',{action:'myajax',yourdata:"mydata"}).done(function(data)
    {
        //do stuffs
    });
```

Update:

So basically if you want to have ajax request inside wordpresss, you need to define these things and use it like this. the "action" parameter is the function name which you want to call. And you need to put the PHP code into your current theme's function.php.